# Expand Treeview promise

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I am helping a client out with some KendoUI stuff and we're using a treeview for an organizational hierarchy.

They have a search box (autocomplete) above the tree that, when they select someone, it expands the tree, finds them in the tree, selects them and if they are out of view (treeview is in scrollable `div`), it scrolls them into view.

The problem I am having is, my scrollTop animation is happening before the treeview has finished expanding all the way. (I should mention that I turned `loadOnDemand` off on the tree (for now) to expedite expanding the whole tree with `expand('.k-item'))`.

Some code:

```
//in the autocomplete select event handler:
treeView.expand('.k-item');

treeView.select(selectedItem);

var treeTop = treeView.element.offset().top,
elTop = treeView.select().offset().top,
offsetDiff = elTop - treeTop;

treeView.element.animate({scrollTop: offsetDiff}, 100);
```

if I wrap the `animate` in a timeout (of about 300 mils), it works for medium sized organizations. But if we have a large organization that may not be enough time.

What would be better is if I could tap into a promise. I tried:

```
treeView.expand('.k-item').promise().done(//animate);
```

and even tried wrapping the `expand` in a function with a `defer` and `promise`, but the call for `expand` comes back before the tree is fully expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be enough to use `setTimeout` with a value that is larger than what you pass as `options.animation.expand.duration` (the setting defaults to 200, I think).

If you want to wrap the `expand` method in a promise, I think something like this should work:

```
kendo.ui.TreeView.fn.expand = (function(expand) {
    return function(nodes) {
        var that = this,
            deferred = $.Deferred(),
            animationDuration = this.options.animation.expand.duration;

        setTimeout(function() {
            expand.call(that, nodes);
            setTimeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            }, 5 + animationDuration);
        }, 5);

        return deferred.promise();
    }
})(kendo.ui.TreeView.fn.expand);
```

Comment: I did try wrapping in a promise, and it didn't work for me. It wasn't extending the treeview though, because the treeview doesn't really expand recursively, I did that myself. :0) I will try this though. I did end up using a timeout, the problem is, I don't know how big the tree is going to be (it's for org charts for some large companies and small). The timeout I used was 300 and it worked for trees with nodes less than 1000.  Thanks!

Comment: I can take another look at it if you can create a demo; if loadOnDemand is false, expand(".k-item") should expand everything in one go, no matter how big the tree